# Change to a directory with white space...works in .ipynb but not .py?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, cd

Trying to convert my Jupyter Notebooks to python scripts so that I can automate them on a daily basis. On Mac.

This works in Notebooks with no problem:

```
cd '/Volumes/GoogleDrive/My Drive/dailyScripts'
```

But then when I try to run it as a .py file, there's various issues.

- First, it rejects the quotes as invalid syntax.

```
cd '/Volumes/GoogleDrive/My Drive/dailyScripts'
   ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

- So I drop the quotes but then obviously it doesn't like the white space without a backslash.

```
cd /Volumes/GoogleDrive/My Drive/dailyScripts
                          ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

- So then I added a backslash but now it doesn't like that \ in Python is a line continuation character.

```
cd /Volumes/GoogleDrive/My\ Drive/dailyScripts
                                              ^
SyntaxError: unexpected character after line continuation character
```

I've also tried double quotes. Not sure what other options there are. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because `cd` is a shell command for a command line interface (e.g. terminal on mac/linux, or Command prompt/Powershell on windows). IPython notebooks are "smart" such that when they see you begin a line with `cd ...` it will automatically run it through the pseudo-terminal for you.

Python on its own has no knowledge of `cd` or other shell programs, instead it bundles all of its interfacing with the operating system inside of the `os` module in the standard library. So, to change the directory from inside of a python script, you'll need to use the `os` module and use the `chdir` function like so:

```
import os

os.chdir("/Volumes/GoogleDrive/My Drive/dailyScripts")
```

Further reading on [os.chdir](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/os_chdir.htm)

Comment: `cd` part is not quite right. It is `!cd` that IPython sees directly as a shell command i.e., `!` makes it so; `%cd` is interpreted as [a magic command](https://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/interactive/magics.html#magic-cd) (`%automagic` being enabled allows to write `cd` only). e.g. `!cd -q` isn't the same as `cd -q`. They happen to share the same name.